# bootwindow problem at startup

Tags: boot, startup, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace GRUB with Windows NT Bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115968/how-to-replace-grub-with-windows-nt-bootloader)

Using Windows and Ubuntu, I got a black screen with white letters and just three options: "Start Windows", "Start Ubuntu" or "Windows recovery".

Now I installed Ubuntu on an extra drive and get a purple window with a whole bunch of options that I dont need, want or don't even know what the do,

Does someone knows how to help me or how to get the old bootloader back, without uninstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: purple window? is it the screen where you can put your password in?

Comment: Probably not @suli8. The purple window Yakke is referring is the grub menu.

Comment: @Yakke that purple window you are looking at is the grub menu. The boot option created by Windows was overwritten when you installed Ubuntu. You might find these resources about Grub2 helpful https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275 (Ubuntu Forums: Grub2 Basics)

Comment: Not a dupe of replace grub with NT.  Black screen with start windows, start ubuntu, windows recovery means it's a wubi install.  If start ubuntu is selected, then it chainloads grub.  So what he really wants to do is configure grub from within wubi to not have menu options/nowait or similar

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a different bootloader. When you were using Wubi Ubuntu was installed within Windows and the Windows bootloader was used to choose between which operating system you wished to boot into

[image]

Now that you have installed Ubuntu onto a different drive a different bootloader, Grub2, has been installed. There is no need to worry that you have broken anything :)

You now will have a few more options when you start your computer, though they may at first glance seem a bit more complicated than the simple Ubuntu or Windows options.

[image]

The items and order of the menu may vary slightly on your system but should be basically the same.

- The first option on the list in the picture above is the normal boot
  into Ubuntu option
- The second is to boot into [Ubuntu in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194/what-is-the-recovery-option-in-the-grub-menu)
- The previous Linux versions option allows you to boot into Ubuntu
  using an older version of the kernel which can be useful in a rare
  occasion in which an update causes problems
- The memtest options allow you to check your RAM for errors
- And finally you should have an option to boot into Windows (there may
  also be a further option to boot into Windows in recovery mode)