# Directly shut down

Tags: shutdown, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, which is installed on Intel core i3 laptop. Sometimes it hangs fully and don't respond at all. In this situation, I shut it down directly 5 times (total after installation)from power switch. Will it make any problem on my system? Is there any "repair system" like option in Ubuntu like Windows (insert boot disk to repair windows)?

Comment: we should have to know what causing such problem . log will be available with dmesg command , so type dmesg > dmesg.txt in terminal and paste that in pastebin and then give the link .

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

First, powering-off the system using the `power` button is **not** shutting down, you just force remove the power supply to your system. This can not only damage your Ubuntu, but also damage your personal files which are open. Yes, of course, you don't have an option when your computer just freezes and fails to normally `shut down`. Yes, Ubuntu does have a recovery option, the option just below your Ubuntu 12.04 at boot-time is the `recovery` option, there are many more options, this one is installed when you install Ubuntu. Sorry for not being of help to your primary problem. But please specify if "sometimes" is absolutely any random time, or after a specific period of time always, or on opening a specific application.

Comment: No, my word "sometimes" is not any absolutely any random time. It only happens sometimes as I mentioned 5 times total after installation. It happens when I open any application which makes CPU to go to maximum or sometimes when I open windows 7 in VirtualBox. Can you please make me understand the whole process of doing recovery of Ubuntu 12.04 at boot-time recovery?

Comment: If you can boot into the recovery option in grub menu, you would see a number of options like logging into a command-line only interface, recovering your lost password, remounting your partitions as read-only, etc. See if [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1194/what-is-the-recovery-option-in-the-grub-menu) offers some help.