# How do I add another main user in Xubuntu with gksu?

Tags: xubuntu

I want to add another main user that has sudo rights to do everything on my system.

How can I start the "Users and Groups" application without using that name?

Because I have a rights problem on my computer, I cannot start it as the main user, only with `gksu`

what is the internal name of that program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is users-admin

You can Alt+F2 then run

```
users-admin
```

To add a new user you will need to supply the admin password (assuming you are the first user, that will be yours)

To do so via command line, use the adduser command.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto#Command-line

If unable to do so from within a booted system, run the recovery mode from your boot menu and use a root terminal.

[What is the "recovery" option in the grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194/what-is-the-recovery-option-in-the-grub-menu)

You will need to mount as read/write prior to making any changes from there. ( see answer here [Unable to mount filesystem as read-write in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254223/unable-to-mount-filesystem-as-read-write-in-recovery-mode) )

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Comment: I tried `gksu users-admin` and the window opens, but the window doesen't finish loading, it stayes greyed out

Comment: use it without gksu - then supply password when asked.

Comment: that is the problem at my computer: I am not asked, that's why I wanted to try it with gksu

Comment: How can I add a new user without user-admin?

Comment: command line - probably from recovery menu. You would probably be wise to deal with the system permissions issue you have.

Comment: thanks, that worked: I created it on the commandline: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto#Command-line